# how to bind custom action to submit button on a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I made a form, but I don't know how to collect data from it and after pressing submit button redirect user to adding/fill.erb file, here is my form:

```
  file: adding/counter.erb

  <%= simple_form_for :counter do |f| %>

  <%= f.input :first_name, :collection => 0..10 , :prompt => "How many?" %>

  <%= f.input :last_name, :collection => 0..10 , :prompt => "How many?" %>

  <%= f.input :city, :collection => 0..10 , :prompt => "How many?" %>

  <%= f.input :postal, :collection => 0..10 , :prompt => "How many?" %>

  <%= f.input :street, :collection => 0..10 , :prompt => "How many?" %>

  <%= f.input :job, :collection => 0..10 , :prompt => "How many?" %>

  <%= f.input :role, :collection => 0..10 , :prompt => "How many?" %>

  <%= f.button :submit, 'next step', :style => "margin-top: 20px;" %>
<% end %>
```

I know it is a lame question, but I'm working on it for several hours and I don't know what to do:/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear, but it sounds like your trying to set the URL the form is posted to? If so, you should be able to do this:

```
 <%= simple_form_for :counter, :url => {:controller => "counter", :action => "fill} do |f| %>
```

Comment: thanks, but my friend helped me in other way. He said that I need model with same name as form name - I didn't know about it. Anyway, thanks to you, I know now how to set the URL to the form:)